# How to set ouput of the command execution in gVim to be in gVim window in Windows?

Tags: windows, vim

From time to time I use gVim in windows. I am used to running commands with `:!`which in Linux outputs into gVim window but in Windows the new command line window is opened. How to force gVim to output it in its window?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: [Display output of shell commands in new window](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window)

The `:!` command is useful for running shell commands from Vim. It has one possible drawback: the command output is not displayed in a Vim window, so it can't be accessed with Vim's powerful editing tools. This is easy to fix with `:read !command` which inserts the output to the current window.

Comment: I read this before but this is not what I need. I need to have output displayed in the Windows window but not in Vim window. The type of displaying when you see `Press Enter or type command to continue` after doing which it disappears. So its like sort of Vim terminal/command line.